# copy data to a sheet from another based on matching values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a little different than my last question, but am unable to transfer the code for that to this.

Sheet 1 has individual contacts with company name. Each individual has one name, but company name may show up several times based on how many individuals in the sheet. So:

```
Name        Company       Work Address
John Smith  ABC Company
Jim Smith   XYZ Company
Bob Smith   ABC Company
```

Sheet 2 has Companies with their work address:

```
Company        Work Address
ABC Company    1234 Street, USA
XYZ Company    5678 Street, USA
```

How do I script so that the company addresses go over to the individual contact sheet?

I've tried using arrays, and searching for row/col indexes, but I am missing something. This code has got me the closest, but can't quite make it work (The code column and row numbers don't match with the sample, they are just the current arrays I am trying to work on, fyi):

```
function populateCofieldsincontact() {
  var writeSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('POCs');
  var sourceSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('Businesses');

  var writeData = writeSheet.getRange(1, 6, writeSheet.getLastRow(), 5).getValues();Logger.log(writeData)
  for (var w = 0; w < writeData.length; w++ ) {

    var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
    var dest = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++ ) {
      if (writeData ==sourceData[i][0].toString().match(writeData)) {
        dest.push(sourceData[i][2]); 
      }
    }
  }
  if (dest.length > 0 ) {
      writeSheet.getRange(2,10,dest.length,1).setValue(dest.toString());
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

quick update - I am able to get the setValue (not setValues that won't work for some reason) and write the addresses in the correct column, but only way I could think to get it write in loop was to use getLastRow, and I only know how to do that for the sheet. So I wind up having all the addresses in the correct column, but written in rows starting at the bottom of where the actual data is. I can't figure out how to get it to write into the top row, then downward, ugh.

**FINAL** (hopefully) Code:  I inserted a `[w][0]` next to the second mention of `writeData` on line 13 of @Adam's code and it seems to be working after a few tests. Thanks @Adam and @Serge!!:

```
function populateCofieldsincontact() {
  var writeSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('POCs');
  var sourceSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('Businesses');

  var writeData = writeSheet.getRange(2, 6, writeSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 12).getValues();
  var dest = [];
  var temp;

  for (var w = 0; w < writeData.length; w++) {
    temp = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
      if (writeData[w][0] == sourceData[i][0].toString().match(writeData[w][0])) {
        temp = sourceData[i][11];
        break;
      }
    }
    dest.push([temp]);
  }
  if (dest.length > 0 ) {
      writeSheet.getRange(2, 13, dest.length, 1).setValues(dest);  Logger.log(dest)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works as expected, hopefully my assumptions are correct *(edit: typo corrected as per comment)*:

```
function populateCofieldsincontact() {
  var writeSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('POCs');
  var sourceSheet = sskey.getSheetByName('Businesses');

  var writeData = writeSheet.getRange(2, 6, writeSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
  var dest = [];
  var temp;

  for (var w = 0; w < writeData.length; w++) {
    temp = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
      if (writeData[w][0] == sourceData[i][0].toString().match(writeData[w][0])) {
        temp = sourceData[i][2];
        break;
      }
    }
    dest.push([temp]);
  }
  if (dest.length > 0 ) {
      writeSheet.getRange(2, 10, dest.length, 1).setValues(dest);
  }
}
```

I guess there are a few issues with your code, but I think the important message (which took a noob like me a fair while to work out) is that when you use getValues and setValues, you are always dealing with 2-dimensional arrays, even if the array is only one column wide. Hence the square brackets in the `dest.push([temp])` bit - you are actually progressively pushing an array with a length of one onto the dest array.

Comment: Hi Adam, I think you got it right!  Just one detail: one can remove the very last IF statement since dest array will never be empty as the null value and its square brackets are there as default values... - cheers

Comment: Yes true Serge, I left it in there in case the OP wanted it for a reason, but you're right, it really serves no purpose. Perhaps one could do `if (writeSheet.getLastRow() < 2) return;` at the start to check there is data in the writeSheet.

Comment: @AdamL I tried it and nothing happened. My logs either showed no data or an array of nulls based on what I logged. Guess this can't be done.

Comment: @AdamL, thanks but I don't necessarily want code for a reason :-) I just want it to work - if it takes 800 lines of code I'll be happy, I just want it to work, thx for taking a look at this.

Comment: @AdamL - I think Ive got it - on line 13 of your code, I inserted a `[w][0]` next to the second `writeData` and it's acting the way it should. i've tested with some other columns and so far so good - thanks a ton!!

Comment: Ooops you're right indeed, the comparison had of course to be done with the[w][0] on both sides... I didn't see it either :-)  good thinking!

Comment: Yes oops indeed, haha. Sorry to lead you astray and thanks for working it out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two loops and iterate the second loop in each step of the first one.
If no match is found in the second loop then you should push an empty item in the first array to keep the data alignment in the first data sheet.
I'm sure you can go through this...

Comment: thx, i did try two loops - I even tried a third array to "squish" the writedata into to force it to go to the top line (row 2) instead of the bottom of all the data (as I noted was happening in my quick update). For hours I have tried everything and worked on this til midnight. I've got a business to run and stuff like this that should be simple are an absolute headache.

Comment: I understand for sure you don't want to spend your life on this... that's why we try to help ;-) Adam brought you a good solution... at least I thought until I saw your comment...He'll sure come back and see what happens

Comment: Oh no I appreciate it immensely, I am frustrated with google not with anyone - the help I get here is great - but I do try to exhaust all my mental juices before coming here. I see too many questioners just post a "do this for me" but I try to get as far as I can with as many tries before coming here. Unfortunately the other answer did not work. I just don't get it.

Comment: If there was a way to show a screehshot I'd show what I mean that my latest code last night writes the data in the correct column, but at the bottom of all the other data - if I could just squeeze it up to the proper row, I'd be good. Wouldn't even care if it was code cheating, I just want it to work :-)

Comment: wait - I got it - tinkered with adam's code - it was missing the `[w][0]` in line 13 - Ive tested with other columns and it seems to be working as it should